# Validating React-Draft-WYSIWYG input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using a **validation** function in my form, that checks whether a field is **empty** or not. This works for normal text input boxes, but not for the React-Draft-WYSIWYG box.

I want to check if the WYSIWYG box is *empty*, and if it is, display an error message i.e. `this.state.descriptionError`

This is my state:

```
state = {
 name: "",
 description: [],
 nameError: "",
 descriptionError: "",
}
```

And this is my React-draft-WYSIWYG form element:

```
<Form>
 <Label>Description</Label>
  <Editor
   editorState={this.state.description}
   toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
   wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
   editorClassName="editorClassName"
   onEditorStateChange={this.onDescChange} />
    <div>
     {this.state.descriptionError}
    </div>
</Form>
```

My validate function is as follows:

```
validate = () => {
    let nameError = "";
    let descriptionError = "";

    if(!this.state.name) {                  // Checks if field is empty
      nameError = "Please enter a name";
    }

    if(this.state.description === "<p></p>↵") {          // The problem
      descriptionError = "Please enter a description";
    }

    if (nameError || descriptionError) {
      this.setState({nameError, descriptionError});

      return false;
    }
      return true;
  };
```

It works fine with the `name` field because it equals an empty string. But with the React-Draft-WYSIWYG, it's not a string, and so I'm unsure what to set `this.state.description` to.

Any help or advice is much appreciated, and I can quickly update my answer if you need more detail.

Comment: what is the value of description?

Comment: That's what I'm not completely sure about. When an input is entered in the WYSIWYG box, it's stored in state as a big, complex object with lots of different dropdowns. Therefore I don't know how to target the value when it's in state. Before I POST it to an API I convert it to a HTML string, hence the `<p><p>`, but I know this isn't right.